# How can i get webview to remember cookies?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I am currently developing an app using Android `webView` however, I have ran into a problem. When a user logs into the app a cookie is created for them, this cookie is then used to check who they are throughout all the web pages. But, when the app is closed and reopened the cookies are lost. Is there any way that I am able to stop the cookies from being removed each time the app is closed.

This is my code for the `webView`:

```
String url = "http://app.tantami.co.uk/activity_hpv/uk.co.tantami.app/load.php?app_id=1.1";
WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.web1);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl(url);
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Yes, but CookieSyncManager is no longer used so wasn't sure what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`CookieSyncManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html) to save it, **ex**:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    }
);
```